# GPG Can't connect to S.gpg-agent: Connection Refused

Tags: gnupg, pgp, gpg-agent

I am attempting to set up gpg preset passphrase caching using the gpg agent so I can automate my file encryption process. In order for the gpg-agent to run and properly cache the passphrase, it seems there needs to be a **S.gpg-agent** socket located within the ~/.gnupg/ directory that gets generated in the root directory when I set up gpg and gpg-agent.

What I have done (and which seemed to work in the past) is I would start up everything as root and copy over the contents of the /.gnupg directory to my less privileged user and grant permissions to that socket and directory to the user. The commands I ran to start up the gpg-agent daemon and cache passphrase:

```
gpg-agent --homedir /home/<user>/.gnupg --daemon
/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset --passphrase <passphrase> <keygrip>
```

gpg-agent process seems to be running just fine but I get the below error from the second line:

```
gpg-preset-passphrase: can't connect to `/home/<user>/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': Connection refused
gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Input/output error
```

I have made sure the socket exists in the directory with proper permissions and this process runs as root. It seems that this socket is still inherently tied to root even if I copy and modify permissions. So my questions are

1. How exactly does this socket get initialized?
2. Is there a way to do so manually as another user?

To add, the agent process seems to run just fine for both users but where I get a little hazy is how the gpg-preset-passphrase is using the socket and if its that or the agent that is refusing the connection to `S.gpg-agent`
I also assume that I don't need to explicitly start the agent but figured I would this so that I could set any values such as the homedir if needed.

Comment: gpg-agent should normally be run as daemon, and not be invoked manually. See https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html and https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent. Hint: is there a directive `use-agent` in your gpg.conf file ? Another hint: GNOME Keyring may be running on your system and interfering.

Comment: Thanks, I believe by default it will use the agent. I took a look and couldn't find any instance of the keyring running, additionally, it seems when I run as root, gpg-agent seems able to use that socket. Does this still seem like a permissions issue?

Comment: I'd say it works with root because it runs in its own shell and its own context. But I would check the permissions for all files in /home/<user>/.gnupg/. To make sure no files were added with root permissions while running gpg-agent as root in your home directory. You could just wipe S.gpg-agent.

Comment: Tried a few methods of removing the socket and recreating it, along with the .gnupg directory. I installed the gpg packages as root, perhaps this could have something to do with it, where root has ownership to certain binaries that my user is attempting to access?

Comment: Are you using GnuPG v1 or v2 ? What is the output of `gpg-agent --version` and `gpg --version` ?

Comment: gpg-agent and gpg are both 2.2.16. I neglected to add that I was running this on RHEL7, which was a contributing factor to my issue. I have added it as an answer but in short when I disabled selinux, the connection refused issue disappeared. Thank you for talking through it with me, it definitely led me on the right path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was unrelated to the `gpg-agent` and `gpg-preset-passprhase`.

Note: This is *not* a permanent solution but it did allow me to get past the issue I was facing.

After modifying the `/etc/selinux/config` and disabling SE Linux, I no longer experienced the permissions issue above. SE Linux is a Linux kernel security module developed by Red Hat (I am currently running this on RHEL7). It seems the next step will likely be to make sure these binaries and packages are allowed access from my user using `audit2allow`. Bit more information on this here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow